# how to pause DynamicAnimator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

i keep seeing these methods,

```
– dynamicAnimatorDidPause:  required method
– dynamicAnimatorWillResume:  required method
```

But i've not found a way to call them. Ive set up an animator and called `<UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate>` in the .h, but I cannot seem to call pause on the `self.animator` for some reason.

Anyone have any tips for me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are delegate methods, which means that you don't call them, they get called for you. You implement a delegate to get informed about certain events

The dynamic animator pauses by itself when all movement stops. Try adding a gravity effect with no collision boundaries. The animator should pause when all dynamic items fall offscreen.

Comment: hmm, gotcha. What if i want to force a pause myself?

Comment: I keep getting this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIAttachmentBehavior pause]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16539ac0'`

Comment: when i run ` [[self.dynamicAnimator.behaviors objectAtIndex:2] pause];`

Comment: The method "pause" doesn't exist, that's why you get an unrecognized selector. Pausing isn't really supported, but you could try removing all the behaviors from the animator: `[animator removeAllBehaviors];`.

Comment: I'm just having a problem, when i move something it runs so many calculations with out the object really even moving. Its just jumping back and forth 1px at a time. seems like a waste. wish i could just pause. Thanks man.

Comment: actually, the `dynamicAnimatorDidPause` method only runs when there's a condition that stops the animation, such as gravity/collision.  The dynamic animator will not pause in response to a view with gravity moving off screen.  You can instead add a action block to the gravity behavior to check if the view with gravity has moved off screen.